# NSTextView with text bubbles

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

What technique to use, to create a TextView, containing text bubbles for email, similar as in email

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an NSTokenField. 
Take a look at that and the NSTokenFieldCell classes. 
If what you need to do is highly custom, you might want to look at third party token field implementations that are more flexible.